# Bash in docker container has weird behaviour: "prompt jumps around"

Tags: bash, shell, docker

recently run into a problem regarding my docker-shell, as seen below.
Anybody any clue whats going on? I never had that problem and don't even know what to google...

- It only happens in the docker container, my local shell seems fine.
- Switching shell in the container wasn't successful.
- Scripts to enter docker seem fine; tried with normal command, no success.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

[image: bash]

Comment: Since today I experience same behavior.

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` say (when run inside the container shell) ?
You can also try `reset; stty sane` and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @zeppelin Reset worked in my case. Thanks!!

Comment: My docker shell runs xterm and on my mac it's xterm-256color.
a simple reset of the terminal fixes it temporarily and I placed it into the containers .bashrc for now. But, is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Okay, changing $TERM to the same as host doesn't do anything. reset fixes the bash, but docker attach still looks like a staircase.

Funny thing is, it happend for no reason. Before the weekend it worked just fine. I'm using Docker Edge and as far as I remember, there was no update.

Comment: Seems like Docker Edge 17.06 is the culprit. 17.05 works like a charm.